# Undefined variable on returning list of data

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to return a list of data through a view called 'kodeabsensianak'. Here's the snippet on view file.

```
@foreach ($data as $item)
                <tr class="hover-actions-trigger">
                  <td class="align-middle text-nowrap">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="avatar avatar-xl">
                        <div class="avatar-name rounded-circle"><span>{{ $item -> kode_absen }}</span></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="ms-2">{{ $item -> nama_kabsen }}</div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="align-middle text-nowrap">{{ $item -> keterangan }}</td>
                  <td class="w-auto">
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group hover-actions end-0 me-4">
                      <button class="btn btn-light pe-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Edit"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></button>
                      <button class="btn btn-light ps-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Delete"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span></button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="align-middle text-nowrap">{{ $item -> created_at }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Here's the Controller file.

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = KodeAbsensi::all();
        return view('kodeabsensianak', compact('data'));
    }
```

I tried to write

```
return view('kodeabsensianak')->with('data', $data);
```

and got the same result. I tried to pass thru dd($data), and also displayed same result. I tried to create other view of list data using the same method and it worked.

Comment: when you do dd($data) in controller, what info appers? All records of KodeAbensi?

Comment: It showed this Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1122 ▼
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}

Comment: There's is no data yet in the db, but even there's no data yet it should return the normal view right with blank data?

Comment: Yes it should. Some erro show in the screen? what happen?

Comment: Ok, this is little bit silly though but I tried to change my app route and it worked lol. Previously, it was /kode-absensi-anak, and I tried to change it to /kodeabsensianak and it work. I don't why this solution work to be honest

Comment: I guess the route == view file name?

Comment: They dont need to be the same
But you have to reference the right function, like:
Route::get('/kode-absensi-anak', YouController::index)....
And check if the imports ( of the model and controller ) are right

Comment: Well, that explains it, I think it's typo issue on my web.php file. Thank you for the explanation!